# How to compare column values using closed xml?

Tags: c#, excel, closedxml

I have a table in Excel

```
 col1 col2
 2      4
 1      5   
 5      3
 8      7
```

I need to compare 2 columns, col1 & col2. If the values from column col2>col1 then fill in the cell in the column col2 in red color. If the values from column col2

I wrote an example method, but I do not know how to fix it further.

```
private static void BackroundColor(string filePathNameExcel) 
{
    int i = 1;
    using (XLWorkbook wb = new XLWorkbook(filePathNameExcel))
    {
        IXLWorksheet ws = wb.Worksheet("sheetMy");
        int col = 1;
        for (int j = 1; j <= col; j++)
        {
            if (j == 3)
            {
                for (int irow = 1; irow <= i; irow++)
                {
                    if (ws.Cell(irow, 3).GetString() == "2")  
                    {
                        string dat = ws.Cell(irow, 3).GetString();
                        ws.Cell(irow, 1).Style.Fill.BackgroundColor = XLColor.Red;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        wb.SaveAs(filePathNameExcel, true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not able to fully understand your codes logic without seeing more of your data format so I made a few assumptions and simplified it for this example.

*Starting Data*

[image]

*Code*

```
private static void BackroundColor(string filePathNameExcel)
{
    using (XLWorkbook wb = new XLWorkbook(filePathNameExcel))
    {
        IXLWorksheet ws = wb.Worksheet("sheetMy");
        int lastRow =  ws.LastRowUsed().RowNumber();

        // Loop each row
        for (int irow = 1; irow <= lastRow; irow++)
        {
            // Check if column 1 row value is less then column 2 row value
            if ((double)ws.Cell(irow, 1).Value <  (double)ws.Cell(irow,2).Value)
            {
                ws.Cell(irow, 2).Style.Fill.BackgroundColor = XLColor.Red;
            }
        }

        wb.SaveAs(filePathNameExcel, true);
    }
}
```

*Result*

[image]